# Plato or Aristotle on trading lives

Tags: aristotle, plato, life

I am sure I remember either Plato or Aristotle saying that most people, if a god approached them with an offer to trade their life for someone else's, would run away.  But I have been wrong before with memories like this.  Can anyone here identify such a passage in Plato, or in Aristotle?